# c program about grep

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, dfa, nfa

im having trouble with this code ,its about search string from file after converting to dfa and nfa 
whenever i try to access argv value, it give " 0x7fffffffe977 "XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnom"... " maybe garbage value? though im not increment the argv (?)

though i have parameter in arguments such as -s 'c.h.a.r' /usr/share/dict/words
can someone suggest why this bug happen?

```
//parameter -s 'c.h.a.r' /usr/share/dict/words

#include "regmatch.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

#define BUFSIZE 256

int debug = 0;     
char *reg_string;

static void do_grep(FILE *fp);
static void usage_exit(void);
static void show_region(char *p, char *from, char *to);
static char *match_line(char *str, char **cpp);
static char *match_string(char *str);

static int vflag = 0;  
static int sflag = 0;  
static int dflag = 0; 
static char *progname;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE *fp;
  char c, doption = '0';
  ptree *root;


  if ((progname = strrchr(*argv, '/')) == NULL)
    progname = *argv;
  else
    progname++;

/*option*/
  while (--argc > 0 && (*++argv)[0] == '-' ) { //parameter -s 'c.h.a.r' /usr/share/dict/words, but it not detect any string in argv[0] so this not 
enter while loop why?
    while ((c = *++argv[0])) {
      switch(c) {
      case 'v':
    vflag = 1;
    break;
      case 's':
    sflag = 1;
    break;
      case 'd':
    dflag = 1;

    if (!(isdigit(doption = *++argv[0]))) {
      fatal_error("error");
      usage_exit();
    }
    break;
      default:
    fatal_error("there is error in option");
    usage_exit();
    break;
      }
    }
  }

  if (argc-- < 1) {
    fatal_error("error");
    usage_exit();
  }

  reg_string = *argv++;

  if (dflag) {
    if (sflag || vflag) {

      fatal_error("cannot input -d and -s option together");
      usage_exit();
    }
    switch(doption) {
    case '1':
      lexer();
      break;
    case '2':
      parse();
      break;
    case '3':
      make_nfa();
      break;
    case '4':
      make_dfa();
      break;
    default: 
      fatal_error("-d option 1 until 4");
      usage_exit();
      break;
    }
    exit(0);  
  }

  //make dfa
  get_token();
  root = eval_expr();  //make tree
  if (curr_token != EOREG) 
    parse_error();
  gen_nfa(root);    //change to nfa
  gen_dfa();        //change to dfa



  if (argc < 1) {

    do_grep(stdin);
  } else { //if parameter include file name


    while(*argv){ //here also the value of argv is weird , it give endless loop ....

    printf("%s",argv[0]);


    while (argc-- > 0) {
      if ((fp = fopen(*argv++, "r")) == NULL) {
    fatal_error("cant open file");
    exit(1);
      }
      do_grep(fp);
      fclose(fp);
    }

    }

  }

  return 0;
}
```

[argv change to weird value after programename line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qw1Q.png)

[when first debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mth9.png)

Comment: You have your formatting broken. Please fix.

Comment: Your second command line argument is ‘-s’. Your third command line argument is ‘c.h.a.r’. The while loop condition stops at the third command line argument.

Comment: The whole `*++argv[0]` looks so complicated and weird. Modifying argc and argv isn’t usually the best idea, and mixing dereferencing, increment and indexing in one statement is very unclear. Might be a lot better to take the values in separate variables and work on those. Otherwise after a while even you don’t remember what the code is doing and why.

Comment: @ЯрославМашко i added picture argv value change to weird value in lin  if ((progname = strrchr(*argv, '/')) == NULL), can you explain more about the while loop condition stops at third command line argument?

Comment: Can’t tell from the pictures. Gotta run your code in some environment. I’ll check it later. Btw don’t post links to pictures. It’s bad practice on SO. Better format your output as text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to breakdown the problem, perhaps ask about specific samples you would create.
There could be multiple issues in this code.

For the segfault I recommend single stepping in a debugger .. (such as gdb).  Also, it is best if you isolate the problem to few lines, rather than expect someone to debug your whole code for you.

E.g.:

//parameter -s 'c.h.a.r' /usr/share/dict/words, but it not detect any string in argv[0] so this not enter while loop

Test just this with parameters  -a 'c.h.a.r'

```
/*option*/
  while (--argc > 0 && (*++argv)[0] == '-' )
    printf("opt=> '%s'\n", argv[0]);
```

This works fine, picks up the '-'.

And so on.

Comment: i add picture, i debug with gdb and also with code block but it weird , after  if "((progname = strrchr(*argv, '/')) == NULL) " -> this line argv change to garbage why?

Comment: I do not have this behavior with those lines of your code, it works. remove ALL other code & retry ..